# How to protect the source code of dm script

Tags: dm-script

all:
I'd like to protect my source code of dm script. Now I converted it to gtk file. I'd like to know whether it's possible to decompile it. Thanks.

If someone could give me more idea about protecting source code, I will quite appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTK files (in the current version at least) do not offer any encryption-level security. While the script isn't stored in plain text, I'm certain it is likely that it could be recovered by people with a certain amount of hacking and decryption skills. There is no way known to me to really "protect" your script code from people with enough resolution to do so. I wouldn't do my online banking server by DM script ;c)

Also: Packing scripts into GTK does not "compile" anything. You won't get any efficiency increase neither.

If you need to really "protect" some of your source code, you can only do so by using some proper compiled code. One way to do this would be to have this code be a stand-alone executable that a DM script only calls out to (using `LaunchExternalProcess`)

Comment: In order for readers of this answer to get a feeling for how easy or difficult it might be to reverse-engineer a GTK file, it would be helpful to know whether anything about their internal format and structure is publicly known or easy to work out. As far as I can tell, Gatan provides no information about this, so I assume it is proprietary.